# Swift Crash Extracting Record value from Address Book

Tags: swift, abaddressbook

I'm using Swift to extract data from the AddressBook.  Everything works fine if I build the app using Debug.  But if I build the app using a release configuration, it crashing in this function:

```
private func extractProperty<T>(record:ABRecord, propertyName : ABPropertyID) -> T? {
  return ABRecordCopyValue(record, propertyName)?.takeRetainedValue() as? T
}
```

After some testing, I found that it was crashing when I tried to retrieve a "middleName" that the contact didn't have.  I split the chain out to figure out where exactly it was crashing and it turns out to be crashing in `takeRetainedValue()`.  So even though `ABRecordCopyValue` isn't returning a value, Swift still thinks it is and passes it along the optional chain.  I've tried various means of testing for `nil` but nothing seems to work.

This is only occurring in the release build, though.  Not the debug build.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: For those who will be wondering how to call the function above (like me in a month), use something like this: `var firstname = extractProperty(person, propertyName: kABPersonFirstNameProperty) as String?`

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to try building this under Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) and it works (after spending about an hour converting the project).  So it was definitely a compiler error that has been fixed in the latest Swift.